# Dynamic query with variable value from a table in SSIS 2015

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have Table A that has only one row :

```
CODE    |    DATE
202211  |    2022-11
```

this table will update it self automatically every end of the month (eg: Next month it will change to 202212 and 2022-12)

I want to use 'CODE' and 'DATE' to make my query dynamic, using variable and Execute SQL Task in SSIS.
My original query look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM X
WHERE PERIOD = '202211', EXPDATE > '2022-11'
```

I want to make it so that whenever Table A change, I don't have to change the Query too.
This is what I tried already :

```
DECLARE @Period varchar(50)
DECLARE @Expdate varchar(50)
SET @Period = ?
SET @Expdate = ?
SELECT * FROM X
WHERE PERIOD = @Period, EXPDATE > @Expdate
```

When I try to run using '?' just as the documentation say, it doesn't work, but it run when I change the '?' into hardcode, so I'm pretty sure at least my query works. Am I missing something, or I'm setting the Variable wrong.

This is my variable settings

```
Name     |  Scope  |  Data type  |  Value  |  Expression
position |  MyDtsx |  String     |         |
date     |  MyDtsx |  String     |         |
```

This is my SQL Task setting

```
General
__________________________
Result Set = Single Row
SQLSourceType = Direct Input
SQLStatement = 'SELECT CODE as position, DATE as date FROM A'

Result Set
__________________________
Result Name  |  Variable Name
position     |  User::position
date         |  User::date
```

Comment: If you only have 1 row, why do you need a `where` at all?

Comment: @Stu onyl Table A has one row. The query is the very basic version of the query I have, the real Query actually has several Join and multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax

```
SELECT * 
FROM X
WHERE PERIOD = @Period, EXPDATE > @Expdate
```

Make that

```
SELECT * 
FROM X
WHERE PERIOD = @Period AND EXPDATE > @Expdate
```

However, if table `A` (the source of Period and ExpDate) is in the same database as table `X`, skip the extraneous Execute SQL Task and the variables and just make the query

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM X 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM A 
              WHERE X.PERIOD = A.Code AND  X.EXPDATE > P.[Date]);
```

The comment indicates

> Table A and Table X is from a different database. Sadly the query is actually fine since when I change it to' @Period = '202211'' and '@Expdate = '2022-11'' it run.

A working repo.

My working notes for those following along at home as the name changes messed me a few times.

- Table A's Code = SSIS Variable position = Table X's Period
- Table A's Date = SSIS Variable date = Table X's ExpDate

### SQL Setup

Execute sql task to ensure I have data

```
drop table if exists dbo.so_74394641;
create table dbo.so_74394641
(
Col1 bigint, Period varchar(50), ExpDate varchar(50)
);

insert into dbo.so_74394641
SELECT row_number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)) AS col1, '202211', '2022-12'
FROM sys.all_objects;
```

### SQL Get Values

Execute sql task. Hard coded as I didn't want to create another table in a different database

```
SELECT '202211' AS Code, '2022-11' AS [Date];
```

### DFT Get Data

A data flow. OLE DB Source component using the following query

```
DECLARE @Period varchar(50)
DECLARE @Expdate varchar(50)
SET @Period = ?
SET @Expdate = ?
SELECT * FROM dbo.SO_74394641 AS X
WHERE PERIOD = @Period  and EXPDATE > @Expdate;
```

Parameters mapped

- 0 User::dosition Input
- 1 User::date Input

Control flow

[image]

Data Flow

[image]

Comment: Table A and Table X is from a different database. Sadly the query is actually fine since when I change it to' @Period = '202211'' and '@Expdate = '2022-11'' it run. What I don't understand is why it didn't get the value from the variable instead. Hopefully this make sense